# Return ENS .eth domain with immediate effect

Tags: nft

I would like to immediately return (get rid of) some .eth domains I have recently bought, without waiting a whole year. Can you please advise me how to do this?

Comment: You can send them to the zero address, or any other address actually

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would sending the ENS domain to a zero address make the domain freely available on the market once more?